# Using cglib to implement annotations

Tags: java, annotations, cglib

I'm new to cglib, but it seems like the right tool for the job, so here goes:

Suppose I have an annotation classes `Foo` and `Bar`, and an enum class `B`, such that `Foo` and `Bar` are declared as follows:

```
public @interface Foo {
    public B value();
}

public @interface Bar {
    public B value();
}
```

Now, suppose I have this:

```
public class AnnotationImpl<A extends Annotation, B extends Enum<B>> {
    public AnnotationImpl(Class<A> annotationClass, B value);
    // value() returns value, annotationType() returns annotationClass
    // Implement equals(), hashCode(), toString() as specified
}
```

It seems repetitive to have to subclass `AnnotationImpl` for both `Foo` and `Bar` when they are more or less identical; is it possible to use cglib to have a method `makeImpl()` taking an an annotation class that returns an `AnnotationImpl` that implements that annotation class?  eg. `makeImpl(Foo.class, B.ONE)` returns a `Foo` backed by `AnnotationImpl(Foo.class, B.ONE)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to return the value, implementing an annotation with cglib is quite trivial. However, if you want to correctly implement the `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString` methods, it requires slightly more work.

For doing so, you do not even need cglib, you can simply work with the [JDK proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) that ship with the standard class library. This would work as follows:

```
<T> makeImpl(Class<T> type, Object value) {
  return Proxy.newProxyInstance(type.getClassLoader(),
                                new Class<?>[] { type },
                                new InvocationHandler() {
                                  @Override
                                  Object invoke(Object proxy, 
                                                Method method, 
                                                Object[] args) {
                                    // Fails when incompatible, e.g. hashCode method
                                    // or annotation with incompatible signature.
                                    return value;
                                  }
                                });
}
```

If you wanted to implement an generic proxy for annotations, look at [my libary's `AnnotationInvocationHandler`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/pool/TypePool.java) which implements such a handler. (My library Byte Buddy does things similar to cglib.)